# golang : convert milliseconds to time

Tags: go, time

I need to convert milliseconds to time irrespective of time zone. 
Below is sample code

`i := 1481462220 
 tm := time.Unix(i, 0)`

Currently time.Unix returns time specific to my machine's zone. So, if I change time zone of my machine, it returns a different time. **What I need is time should be same irrespective of time zone of machine.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [GoDoc](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Unix) `time.Unix` :

> Unix returns the local Time corresponding to the given Unix time, sec
>   seconds and nsec nanoseconds since January 1, 1970 UTC.

Hence to get the same time across machines you need to convert the returned local time using [`time.Time.UTC()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.UTC)

So in this case it would be `tm.UTC()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

`tm.UTC()`

UTC() returns tm with the location set to UTC.